# bash when you find two columns delete the first column in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two columns like below

```
0:0:36 hostname-x.y.com:1212/dbname
server.y.com:1012/bname
0:0:9 commom.y.com:9312/xname
windows.y.com:1052/wname
```

Desire output should be as follows

```
hostname-x.y.com:1212/dbname
server.y.com:1012/bname
commom.y.com:9312/xname
windows.y.com:1052/wname
```

Basically, when it finds two columns, it should skip the first column. I have nearly 10k lines. Any suggestions would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

That can trivially be done with `awk` simply with:

```
awk '{print $NF}' filename
```

Which will simply print the last field on each line.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file in `file`:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file
hostname-x.y.com:1212/dbname
server.y.com:1012/bname
commom.y.com:9312/xname
windows.y.com:1052/wname
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh! (funny how I grab `\`` instead of `'` on occasion -- must be a SO thing... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

By seeing your sample of expected output(adding more generic solution) if I get it correctly(you want to print data after digits), could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ +/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ +/){      ##Using match function which matches regex of digits colon digits colon digits then space in line.
  print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)        ##If a match is found then it should print sub-string of line starting from RSTART till RLENGTH.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                        ##1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
'  Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.* //g' < input_file
```

Demo

```
:>cat test.txt
0:0:36 hostname-x.y.com:1212/dbname
server.y.com:1012/bname
0:0:9 commom.y.com:9312/xname
windows.y.com:1052/wname
:>sed 's/.* //g' test.txt
hostname-x.y.com:1212/dbname
server.y.com:1012/bname
commom.y.com:9312/xname
windows.y.com:1052/wname
:>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cut to take the second filed, with " " as delimiter. If the delimiter is not found, the entire line is given in output, as specified by the -f option help section (cut --help)

```
-f, --fields=LIST       select only these fields;  also print any line
                            that contains no delimiter character, unless
                            the -s option is specified
```

The command should be

```
cut -f2 -d" " yourfile
```

**Demo:**

```
root@a036fb1c94fa:~# cat yourfile
0:0:36 hostname-x.y.com:1212/dbname
server.y.com:1012/bname
0:0:9 commom.y.com:9312/xname
windows.y.com:1052/wname 

root@a036fb1c94fa:~# cut -f2 -d" " yourfile
hostname-x.y.com:1212/dbname
server.y.com:1012/bname
commom.y.com:9312/xname
windows.y.com:1052/wname
```